# Change Password Control

Tags: input, users, password, application-state

[image]

My idea of manage password section is to enable only Current password field at first. If the user enters correct password in the field only then the fields beneath it would go in enable state. Would this be a good way of restricting false users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers make user change password, when

- password is near to expiry
- forgot password
- detects a suspicious login, informs user by email/msg and forces the user to change password.

Making the user enter current password makes sense only in the 3rd case. My suggestion would be to avoid asking for current password to an already logged in user. On top of that a non-enabled field might change the mind of the user to change password --> leading to expiry. So don't over-complicate a simple functionality.

Just providing New Password and Re-type Password fields would be best.

Comment: "_Developers make user change password_" In most cases, users can also _choose_ to change their password. In all scenarios, the usual reason for making them enter the current password is to stop a random person passing an unattended PC and changing the password of whoever's logged-in (obviously they _shouldn't_ leave a logged-in PC unattended, but...)